# J2ME Insert a list element into a new form TextField

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I want to insert an element of a list into one new form's Textfield and change its value.
Is it possibe? 
If not, is it possible to change an element of a list at all by selecting it and type a new value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand you, you are looking for a way to manipulate javax.microedition.lcdui.List. In order to "edit" value you need to use [getSelectedIndex()](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/List.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29) (list option selected by user for editing) to [getString(int elementNum)](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/List.html#getString%28int%29).

You can then display this in TextField for editing.

Before "adding" to list you need to delete old element [delete(int elementNum)](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/List.html#delete%28int%29) and then you can insert in this position new value [insert(int elementNum, String stringPart, Image imagePart)](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/List.html#insert%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.microedition.lcdui.Image%29)